# Multi newsticker on mysite

Tags: javascript, jquery, news-ticker

i want to add more 2 or 3 news ticker on my site with news ticker from http://thenewsticker.com.

how, to do it.

thanks. :)

Comment: And why you tag your question with 'jquery' tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [jquery plugin called webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/); you can have multiple rotating tickers per page; all you have to do is create lists like the following

```
<ul id='ticker1'>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

and then do a jquery initialize for each of the lists. Note each list would require a separate id as duplicate ids will be invalid syntax.

```
jQuery('#ticker1').webTicker();
```